# Regex for US Zip code - but make it optional

Tags: angularjs, regex, angular

I need a regex for US zip codes.  I've found lots of examples but none that allow for the zip code to also be optional.  You see, I am using this on a non-required input field so the valid scenarios are a 5 digit zip code, a 5+4 digit zip code, or no zip code at all.  Here is what I have so far but it does not work for the "no zip code at all" scenario:

```
^(\d{5}(?:\-\d{4})?)$
```

Comment: Insert a `?` before `$`: `^(?:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?$`

Comment: Why the angular tags?

Comment: Werner - my mistake, I should have mentioned I was using angular 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to enclose the whole pattern with a non-capturing optional group:

```
^(?:\d{5}(?:-\d{4})?)?$
 ^^^                ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fThrQd/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:`  - start of the optional group

  - `\d{5}` - 5 digits
  - `(?:-\d{4})?` - optional group matching `-` and 4 digits
- `)?` - end of the outer optional group
- `$` - end of string.

Note that it is the `?` quantifier that makes the outer non-capturing group optional (match 1 or 0 times).

You might as well use capturing groups if you want to make your pattern shorter, but it a non-capturing one is more natural to use here since you are not interested in captured subvalues.

Comment: This worked great.  One thing to note if folks come here looking at this, is that I also found that in version 2.0.2 of angular2 there was a bug in the pattern validator where it would treat the field as invalid even if the field was supposed to be optional and no input was supplied. Upgrading to angular2 2.1.0 fixed this.  Thanks all.